# How to output that the input has already been entered

Tags: python

EDIT:
I have tried to submit my task, and it says that "Testing the first example in the question. Your submission attempted to read too much input! This occurred on line 3 of your submission." Does anybody know what this could mean? Or how to fix this issue.

---

I have created this program using Python. If the user enters the same pokemon twice, I would like to make it say that the pokemon has already been captured. (You are already training Eevee)

My code:

```
Pokemon = {}
while True:
  command = input("Command: ")
  if "Capture" in command:
      command = command.split(' ')
      Pokemon[command[1]] = command[2]
      print(command[2])
      print(Pokemon[command[1]])
      #if command[2] in Pokemon:
        #print("You are already training " + Pokemon[command[1]])

  if "Query" in command:
       command = command.split(' ')
       if command[1] not in Pokemon:
           print("You have not captured " +  command[1] + " yet.")
       else:
           print(command[1] + " is level " + Pokemon[command[1]] + ".") 
  else:
    print("Unknown command!")
```

What I want the code to do:

```
Command: Capture Eevee 4
Command: Query Eevee
Eevee is level 4.
Command: Capture Eevee 6
You are already training Eevee!
Command:
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hey there. The answer below should be correct I am just here to give you a small 
improvement for your code. Instead of using "command.split(' ')" you can use "command.split()" without the inner string. The split() command splits strings on empty spaces by default. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

you can trying this:

```
Pokemon = {}
while True:
    command = input("Command: ")
    if "Capture" in command:
        command = command.split(' ')
        if not command[1] in Pokemon:
            Pokemon[command[1]] = command[2]
        else:
            print("You are already training {}!".format(command[1]))
    elif "Query" in command:
        command = command.split(' ')
        if command[1] not in Pokemon:
            print("You have not captured " +  command[1] + " yet.")
        else:
            print(command[1] + " is level " + Pokemon[command[1]] + ".") 
    else:
        print("Unknown command!")
```

output:

```
Command: Capture Eevee 4
Command: Query Eevee
Eevee is level 4.
Command: Capture Eevee 6
You are already training Eevee!
Command:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var = None

if var is None:
    var = input("Command: ")
else:
    print("Already entered!")
```